# Store in the column "status" of the registrations table the value "C" if is a free registration but "I" if is a paid registration

Tags: php, laravel

I have a conference details page where the user can select in a form the quantity of available tickets for the conference that he wants. A conference can have 1 or many tickets and some can be free other paid. This form for the user to select the tickets that he wants has this action:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('conferences.storeQuantities', ['id' => $conference->id, 'slug' => $conference->slug])}}">
...
</form>
```

So when the user clicks in "Next" the code goes to the RegistrationController storeQuantities() this method stores the selected tickets (quantity of each ticket, total, etc) and some other some info in the session and returns the user to the 'conferences.registration' route:

A summary of the storeQuantities():

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
    {
        ....
        $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
        $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['price'] = $price;
        $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
        $total += $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'];
        $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['total'] = $total;

        Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
        return redirect(route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]))->with('total', $total);
    }
```

So then the code goes to the route:

```
Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@displayRegistrationPage',
    'as'   =>'conferences.registration'
]);
```

So the function displayRegistrationPage is called that gets the values in session and redirects the user to the registration page:

```
 public function displayRegistrationPage(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
    {

    ...
    $selectedRtypes = Session::get('selectedRtypes');
    $allParticipants = Session::get('allParticipants');

    return view('conferences.registration',
    ['selectedRtypes' => $selectedRtypes, 'allParticipants' => $allParticipants, 'customQuestions' => $customQuestions, 'id' => $id,
        'slug' => $slug]);
    }
```

So now the registration page is presented to the user. Here there is a form for a user to register in a conference. The form is like:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('conferences.storeRegistration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])}}">
...
</form>
```

**Doubt:** When the form is submited, in this storeRegistration() I want to store in the status column of the registrations table the value "C" (complete) if the total registration price is "0" but if is ">0" I want to store as "I" (incomplete).

Do you know how this can be properly achieved?

```
public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator)
{
...
if ($validator->passes()) {
    $registration = Registration::create([
        'conference_id' => $id,
        'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
        'status' => 'C',   // 'C' if free 'I' if paid
    ]);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if conditional to check the type of status in your array by using general if statment like so:

```
$registration = Registration::create([
        'conference_id' => $id,
        'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
        'status' => ($regprice < 0) ? 'C' : 'I',   // 'C' if free 'I' if paid
    ]);
```

Comment: For $regprice equal to 0 your code will put I (paid) in the database.

Comment: Thanks, but that $regprice comes from where?

Comment: replace $regprice with your registration price thats availabe in your app

Comment: In the "storeQuantities()" method the total price of the selected types are stored in the selectedRtypes array. Is necessary to access in the Registration::create([]) the value of total of the selectedRtypes?

Comment: yes if you want to make a calculation and get a result based on that type.

Comment: Sorry, but Im not understanding. Is not necessary to do no calculation to store in the registrations table, is only necessary to store C or I based on if the registration has 1 or more registration types which that are paid. But Im not understanding how to get the price here "        'status' => ($regprice < 0) ? 'C' : 'I',   // 'C' if free 'I' if paid
".

Comment: you have stored price on session selectedRtypes. Just fetch data from that session and check from that

Comment: Thanks, do you know if is better store in the session "        Session::put('total', $total);
" in the storeQuantities() and then in the storeRegistration use "        $total = Session::get('total');
"? Or dont put the total in the session (Session::put('total', $total)) and get in the storeRegistration (        $selectedRtypes = Session::get('selectedRtypes');
) and then from that get the total of that array, or is the same?